# JS libraries to prettify/ highlight the HTML Code syntax automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add some code to my website (Code to explain to learners or like on W3School and NOT for any text-editor). I can do so, but what I want is that the colors of the various tags, or attributes to change in color by themselves so that code looks beautiful (and Self explanatory to anyone trying to learn any web-designing coarse on my blog or website). Please see the image below:

[image: Beautiful and colorful code]

Can someone suggest me any css,js,or any other extension to include which automatically prettifies my code like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Alex - You have all the rights to vode down or suggest me something else -- "IF YOU YOURSELF HAS ANSWER TO MY QUESTION!", you can't because you dont know buddy! -- Therefore next best thing you can do is vote down! ... ;/

Comment: first im not your buddy :) second, I've read the guidelines of SO and asking for a plugin/library/software is not wanted here, hence the downvote and vote to close. Just google what youre looking for and youll be fine. I know at least 1 plugin that does what you are looking for

Comment: @Alex - There are always exceptions to Rule. I googled it, went through varioius options, then I asked here ... and this is rarest of rare, scenarios of asking any plugin or answer. I am not asking software to edit photographs dude, this is something you wont find eazy - at net or anywhere! ;)

Comment: its actually pretty easy to find. Look at Marcels answer or google http://bit.ly/1N4uA5c

Comment: or: http://bit.ly/1WffMGP really not that hard...

Comment: Now, that is called 'help' - Now you have right to vote it down! ;), Also, I should have used codeword - "Syntax highlighter" than pretty uncommon words! ;)

Comment: I don't like your attitude here Peterson. My reason for the downvote

Comment: @Peterson I dont have to "help" (which is basically just doing something you could have done) to know that you are voilating the SO guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for automatically color your code: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

For quickly tidying up your code you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ 
Just insert the code and press "tidy up"

Comment: Dear - Its not for any text-editor but for writing or explaing code template on 'blog' or 'website'.

Comment: Well i have read the post before editing and it seems that i have got it just wrong.

Comment: Edited my original Post again. That should be what you are looking for.